# Help with Constrained optimization, and Lagrange Multipliers

Tags: calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

How can I find the extremal values of the function $f(x,y,z)=5x-2y+z+17$ under the constraint $x^2 + y^2 + z^2=30$?

Comment: you need the Lagrange method

Comment: Google "Lagrange Multipliers". you will find all you need with a little patience. Additionally, LaTeX markup is appreciated to improve readability. I will submit an edit for you.

Answer (score 1):

Note that you are extremising a linear function on the surface of the sphere.

This is of the form extremise $c^T x$ subject to $\|x\|^2 = 30$.

We know from Cauchy Schwarz that $|c^T x| \le \|c\| \|x\|$ and that
$|c^T x| = \|c\| \|x\|$ **iff** $x $ is a multiple of $c$.

Hence we look for solutions $x = \pm \sqrt{30} {1 \over \|c\|} c$.

Answer (score 0):

consider the function $$f(x,y,z,\lambda)=5x-2y+z+17+\lambda(x^2+y^2+z^2-30)$$
and solve the system
$$f_x=0$$
$$f_y=0$$
$$f_z=0$$
$$f_{\lambda}=0$$

Comment: i tried to do it with the gradient, then i found the system 2*lambda*x - 5=0
2*lambda*y-2=0 and 2*lambda*z-1=0, what do i do next?

Comment: @YazidJanati do not pay too much attention to the answers by mr. graubner

Comment: Solving the system only finds the stationary points, further analysis is needed to find the extrema.